# Safari Web Inspector not Showing elements and Style Panel when debugging iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, developer-tools, safari-web-inspector

I connected iPhone to mac and I enabled Web Inspector in iPhone advanced settings, able to see the page in mac safari but not able to inspect any element and its style in safari. I am not seeing the elements panel or style panel.

Could anyone help me to find those panels to debug the styles, which  i applied to page elements which I am testing in iPhone. I am able to see those panels in debugging the desktop safari pages. see the screenshot[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH3-SW1

Comment: @GobiM What I am asking is, styles and elements panel is missing when i debug iPhone Pages in desktop safari. see the window in top in my screenshot

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The Answer is , need to select the DOM Tree from the dropdown as in the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 50):

If that type of problem ever happens to you in 2021, download and use [Safari Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) instead of the regular Safari

I got the problem with the following config:

- MacOS Big Sur 11.4
- Iphone 10 iOS 14.6

Cheers!

Comment: Correct answer for 2021!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! Any idea what the actual cause of the problem is though? I've never had any issues using the latest production releases of Safari before this and everything on my Mac is up to date.

Comment: Worked for me with host OS Catalina 10.15.7 Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much. I have the latest Big Sur installed 11.4 and latest iOS 14.6 and the web inspector has no elements tab at all when inspecting a site on my phone. The latest Safari tech preview works though. Shame on Apple for letting this through the net.

Comment: Works for me with macOS Big Sur 11.4

Comment: 2021 Video explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3eThi-q_LY

Comment: Correct answer for 1 Nov 2021 with macOS 11.6.1 Big Sur & iOS 15.0.2

Answer (score 24):

Update July, 2021:

Yes, the other answer for using Safari Technology Preview is working for me too: https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Debugging was broken for me with Safari on Big Sur: Version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)

Debugging was working for me with Safari Technology Preview on Big Sur: Release 128 (Safari 15.0)

---

This was incredibly frustrating for me too. It's the small sidebar icon [image: small sidebar icon] on the far top right, with elements tab open.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: This is the most frustrating thing of all time, totally unintuitive to find once hidden and the thing I care most about 50+ % of the time

Comment: I can't believe they made a separate application for this, it's extremely inconvenient.

Comment: @IsabellaMonza sadly it's not a separate application, it's their beta version of the Safari browser. It's just that Safari is currently broken to do this feature ... yet the beta is working https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Comment: @jackhowa Yes, I hope this will be fixed in the next update. Thanks for the info anyway :)

Answer (score 8):

From web inspector select any html element. Now in device it will be highlighted with blue color. The top right corner having expand window to show style, Layers, Node tabs. Select Style and edit css. Refer link given in comment for complete details.[image]

Comment: I am not able to see the elements panel. that is my issue then how can i select using the debugger?

Comment: From your image, your arrow points to the web elements for safari web page and this is not for an mobile device. Check for the pop up window (web Inspector **-iphone ** ip). This window shows the html page of your iphone browser/webview. Select an html tag(DOM tree) from this page, this will select respective element in device. once done you can view the styles pane from top right corner of current source window.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the answer, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

In Safari 11.1.2, when the 'Computed' tab is selected, you can get back up to the non-computed properties (the Style Attributes) level by clicking the arrow beside any of the computed properties. See, for example, the grey arrow next to the `-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing` property in my attached screenshot.

[image: Safari Element Inspector Computed properties sidebar]

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is a normal problem in Catalina and BigSur updates after Mojave. Or if you are upgrading your MacOS to the later versions.  I hope we don't get in Monterey!
I recommend to download - Safari Technology Preview -

BigSur - [Download](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/071-59915-20210701-7aeff054-50c5-4c98-b5b7-4fc517d8a696/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg)

with whatever you have been using.

If you are facing it with other lower versions -
[try from here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Safari)